# Raphael center of scale in transform method

Tags: javascript, raphael

Right now I'm using:

```
r.forEach(
    function (el) {
      el.scale(0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0);
    });
```

to scale each object around (0/0), which is working fine.

The Raphael reference however states that the scale function is deprecated and I'm supposed to use Raphael.transform(...) instead.

I tried:

```
r.forEach(
    function (el) {
      el.transform("S(0.5)");
    });
```

however, this will scale the paths using the image center as the center of scale. How can I achieve the same effect with the transform function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use translation string the same way as parameters of "scale" function:

```
el.transform("s0.5, 0.5, 0, 0");
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot! I was just starting to combine translations and scale operations...

Comment: This helped with scaling a set too. Without fully defining "s" when scaling a set all the objects scale according to their own centers, but with the full definition the whole set scales together.
This just saved me so much time!
Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

```
el.transform("S0.5, 0.5, 0, 0");
```

[solved here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lg2Gy/45/)